# Gallery images wrap in IE but not in other browsers

Tags: css, wordpress, gallery, word-wrap

Here's the situation: [my WordPress Gallery looks fine](http://www.sporttours.net/basketball/) in Firefox, Safari, etc. but running on IE (under Windows), the the last image in the gallery wraps to the next line.

So far, I've tried adjusting the gallery width, padding, inline, block, and changing the number of columns to no avail. There is plenty of room on the row to fit the images.

Here's what I think are the pertinent CSS bits:

```
#gallery-1 {
   float: right;
   height: 70px;
   margin: 1px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   width: 480px;
}

.gallery-icon {
   width: 55px;
   padding: 3px;
   margin: 0;
   float: left;
}

.gallery-columns-7 {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

.gallery-item { 
   float: left;
   margin: 3px;
   padding: 0 2px 0 0;
   width: 55px;
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which version of IE are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix this

```
<dl class="gallery-item">
{
 margin-right: 3px;
 margin-left: 3px;
}
```

Either change it to 1px or delete them or delete just the right or left margin in the styles.css line 1219

Comment: You could have marked the answer as correct if it has solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow: hidden;` in your `.gallery-item` class.

Comment: Wow. Someone hated the answer that much? Was it that unhelpful? Downvotes are ordinarily used to indicate that an answer is so wildly inaccurate or misleading that it shouldn't be considered.

Comment: There should be information as to who has down voted the answer and his reasons for doing so.

Comment: Well I am going to vote for this answer. So atleast the negative votes gets even.